# AWS Custom Api Gateway Response

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, serverless

I am currently implementing the custom authorizer for my AWS lambdas using this template https://github.com/auth0-samples/jwt-rsa-aws-custom-authorizer/blob/master/lib.js.

The thing is that I want to display a custom message whenever the API Gateway response is one of the following: `ACCESS_DENIED`, `EXPIRED_TOKEN` or `UNAUTHORIZED` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/supported-gateway-response-types.html). I assigned the context property with a custom message when generating the policy and now I need to edit my serverless.ts config file to handle these responses. Previously I used the `.yml` file and it looked like that

```
    DenyFailureGatewayResponse:
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse"
      Properties:
        ResponseParameters:
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
        ResponseTemplates:
          application/json: |
            {
              "name":"$context.authorizer.name",
              "message":"$context.authorizer.message"
            }
        ResponseType: ACCESS_DENIED
        RestApiId:
          Ref: "ApiGatewayRestApi"
        StatusCode: "403"
```

But now I switched to the `.ts` file. How can I write similar code using typescript?

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this:

```
"responseParameters": {
  "method.response.header.X-Powered-By": "Serverless", // a string
  "method.response.header.Warning": "integration.response.body", // the whole response
  "method.response.header.Location": "integration.response.body.some.key" // a pseudo JSON-path
},


    custom: {
    ....
      },
      resources:{
    Resources: {
      GatewayResponse: {
        Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse',
        Properties: {
          ResponseParameters:{
            "gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'",
            "gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'*'",
          },
          ResponseType: "ACCESS_DENIED",
          RestApiId:{
            Ref: 'ApiGatewayRestApi'
          }
        },
    }, 
   },
 },
```

ref: https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-offline